# Angular 6 No NgModule metadata found for 'myModule'

Tags: lazy-loading, angular6

It looks like problem with my 'lazy loading'

When I'm trying ng serve, I got this error:

```
ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'ModuleA'.
```

And compilation is waiting. Then if I edit and save file modulea.module.ts it works. But this trick doesn't work with ng build (there is now 'watch' mode) I hope you know what I'm talking about :D

So how can I fix it?

My folders structure:

```
src/
  app/
    views/
       moduleA/
         componenets/
         modulea.module.ts
         modulea-routing.module.ts
       moduleB/
         componenets/
         moduleb.module.ts
         moduleb-routing.module.ts
    ... app components etc
    app.module.ts
    app.routing.ts
```

My app routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
     path: 'modulea',
     children: [
       {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './views/moduleA/modulea.module#ModuleAModule'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
     path: 'moduleb',
     children: [
       {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './views/moduleB/moduleb.module#ModuleBModule'
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Module A:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ModuleARouting } from './modulea-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ModuleARouting
  ],
})
export class ModuleAModule { }
```

Module B:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ModuleBRouting } from './moduleb-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ModuleBRouting
  ],
})
export class ModuleBModule { }
```

Module A and B routing files loading another module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'ModuleA'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'module-a-a'
      },
      {
        path: 'module-a-a',
        loadChildren: './components/module-a-a.module#ModuleAAModule'
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ModuleARouting {}
```

And finally ModuleAA loads components

**EDIT**
I can edit any file (when compile is fail and waiting) to pass it done.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was and error on module name . So check all names , routing names, component names and module names of the module that the error is happening.